# I don't know what's the error in this code

Tags: php, mysql, image, upload

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $img = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $target = 'img/'.basename($img);

    $sql = move_uploaded_file($img, $target);
    if ($sql) {
        echo $img." uploaded";
    }else {
        echo $img." Failed";
    }
}

if(!empty($_FILES['image'])) {
    $path = "img/";
    $path = $path . basename( $_FILES['image']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $path)) {
        echo "The file ".    basename( $_FILES['image']['name'])." has been uploaded";
    } else{
        echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Your logs might or error reporting might tell you.

Comment: this exactly that I expected answer. thanks

Comment: BTW, if the '*Lorem ipsum [...]*' is meant to be the error that that isn't an error.

Comment: @Script47 no man. I add it. for post. otherwise I can't post it. lol

Comment: Instead of posting useless Lorem ipsum text you could describe what the problem is, what you were expecting and stuff. Leap in the dark: folder permissions.

Comment: @kerbholz lorem for post. otherwise I can't post it. it doesn't show any error. just else block works. but the second code blocks is works perfectly. and I want know where's the different between these

Comment: "else block works"... you got two else in your code, describe better your problem.

Comment: in the first code block. think it's better right ?

Comment: Acccording to the [move_uploaded_file doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) there coud be two possibilities. a) filename is not a valid upload file and b) filename is a valid upload file, but cannot be moved for some reason

Answer (score 2):

I have checked your code it is perfectly fine. You need to take care of following few things.

1 - img directory should be have 777 rights.
2 - check your form tag properly.

Below is the sample for you.

```
<?php
if(!empty($_FILES['image'])) {

$img = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$target = 'img/'.basename($img);


//$sql = move_uploaded_file($img, $target); //replace $img with ($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']), you are not provide the tmp path of the image

$sql = move_uploaded_file(($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']), $target);
if ($sql) {
    echo $img." uploaded";
}else {
    echo $img." Failed";
}
}
?>
<form name="frm" id="id" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<input type="file" name="image" id="image" >
<input type="submit" value="Upload" name="Upload">
</form>
```

Let me know if it helps?

Comment: check my code. the first code block is mine. second not. it's already works as I say in comments. thanks

Comment: @userx I have edited the answer

Comment: now it's true. I'v already found the error. thanks bro. :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should post what's the result you are getting and what did you expect,   also you should've posted the html form code too.

The 2 `if`'s seem related but are not connected ... maybe the second one should've been inside the first one ?

In the first `if` you are passing the wrong arguments to the `move_uploaded_file` method, the second one seems be good.

Ensure the "destination dir" is present, in the right location and has the correct permissions. Check apache's error_log for messages that might help.